# bson in mongo-c-driver: update value of already existent field

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I'm working with the mongo-c-driver and I have a doubt with the BSON library. As you can see [here](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_t.html#functions), there are a lot of functions to append data to already existent bson document (We are talking about bson documents in memory, not stored in the database). But I can't find one to update or delete an already existent field. There is a way to modify already existent fields?

Best regards, thanks for your time,

Héctor

Answer (score 0):

You can update or delete a field with the `mongoc_collection_update_one()` function. 
The `"$set"` and `"$unset"` operators should be good enough for simple fields (or `"$push"` and `"$pull"` for arrays), otherwise there is the complete list of operators [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-field/).

Comment: I'm talking about documents in memory created by the driver with [bson_new](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/bson_new.html). Not already stored documents in mongoDB.